# Finding differences between 2 Ubuntu installs

Tags: 20.04, xorg

I have 2 computers running Ubuntu Mate 22.04.3. They are meant to be configured exactly the same. On each computer I'm running a full screen OpenGL application. One one machine xorg uses ~4% CPU consistently. On the other machine xorg uses 20-40% CPU under the exact same load. I'm trying to determine why the difference exists.

I've compared the following commands on both systems:

- apt list --installed
- gsettings list-recursively

In both cases there were no differences between the systems.

What other tools/files/folders/settings are useful to compare two systems?

Thanks!

Comment: hardware difference?  and why not use `top` or `htop` to compare processes?

Comment: The hardware is identical. Both systems using 60 Hz monitors with all connections identical. htop is how I could tell xorg is using more CPU on one system than the other. It doesn't give me the 'why' though.

Comment: You could start switching things to see if the excess load moves. e.g switch monitors, switch HDMI cables, switch GPUs, etc. Is the stepping/patch level on the cpus the same?

Comment: Excellent suggestions ubfan1. Cables, monitors, and video connection types (HDMI vs DP) can make a big difference in video performance/reliability. I tested using the physically same monitor and cable (not just the same models) in 2 different setups. I've gone through the BIOS on both machines and could not see any differences. Next I'm going to try to profile on both machines and see where the extra CPU cycles are coming from. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find any other tools to do this I wrote my own Python script. The script will scan the file system and get the file size and CRC for every file it encounters. A CSV file is output with file name, size, CRC. I then used Notepad++'s compare plugin to compare the CSV file from each system. I haven't found the cause of differences yet, but in case this is useful to anyone else, here is the script:

```
import sys
from zlib import crc32
from os import walk, stat
from os.path import join
import csv

MB = 1024*1024
size_threshold = MB * 512  # don't bother with files > 512 MB
chunksize = MB * 8  # read in 8 MB chunks

# the folders that will be scanned recursively
accepted_roots = ['/bin', '/boot', '/etc', '/home', '/lib', '/opt', '/sbin', '/usr', '/var']


def get_crc(fname, expected_size):
    c = 0
    with open(fname, 'rb') as source:
        read_size = 0
        while True:
            all = source.read(chunksize)
            read_size += len(all)
            c = crc32(all, c)
            if len(all) != chunksize or read_size >= expected_size:
                break
    return c


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
        csvwriter.writerow(['File', 'Size', 'CRC'])

        for check_root in accepted_roots:
            for (root, dirs, files) in walk(check_root, topdown=True):
                print("Checking: " + root)
                for f in files:
                    fname = join(root, f)
                    try:
                        size = stat(fname).st_size
                        c = -1 if (size == 0 or size > size_threshold) else get_crc(fname, size)
                        csvwriter.writerow([fname, str(size), str(c)])
                    except Exception as ex:
                        print(f'Error with {fname}: {str(ex)}')
```

Comment: The program tripwire probably provides the hash you want (it normally checks them regularly to inform you if anything changes).  This does not really answer your question.  Did you try the suggestions in comments?